# Property class validation of curvefit.fitoptions

Tags: matlab, validation, oop, properties, curve-fitting

**TL;DR**: I would like to use [property class validation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-size-and-class-validation.html#bvklfs7-1) to validate [`fitoptions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fitoptions.html) objects, but MATLAB complains.

---

Consider the following classes:

```matlab
% SUPERCLASS:
classdef (Abstract) BaseModel
  % CWLvsT is an abstract parent class for different CWL(T) models.    

  properties (Abstract = true, Access = protected, Constant = true)
    MODEL   (1,1) string
    FITOPTS (1,1) % ???
  end  

end

% SUBCLASS:
classdef RationalFraction < BaseModel
  % This corresponds to a fit of type "rat11".
  properties (Access = protected, Constant = true)
    MODEL = "CWL(T) = (P1 * T + P2) / (T + Q1)";
    FITOPTS = fitoptions('rat11', ...
                  'Lower', [-1, -1E5, -1E4], ...
                  'Upper', [10, 5E5, 5E4], ...
                  'StartPoint', [4, 0, 0]);
  end
end
```

I would like to enforce that subclasses specify some sort of a `fitoptions` object (there are several types) for the `FITOPTS` property.

**Attempt #1**:

The first thing I tried was to create an example `fitoptions` object (according to the definition in the subclass) and see what its `class` was. The result I got was `curvefit.nlsqoptions`, so I tried putting that instead of the `% ???` in the superclass and instantiate the `RationalFraction` class, but got the following error:

```
Error defining property 'FITOPTS' of class 'BaseModel':
Class named 'curvefit.nlsqoptions' is undefined or does not support property validation.
```

**Attempt #2**:

I thought that the above error was a sign that there is some superclass for `fitoptions` against which I should validate the object, so I tried to do `metaclass(optsObj)` on the example object, but got an empty [metaclass](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html). Resorting to a manual search, I did manage to find a good candidate by going over the `MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\curvefit\curvefit\@curvefit` folder - `curvefit.basefitoptions`, but this led to a similar error.

**Attempt #3**:

I noticed that the `fitoptions` objects aren't far from plain `struct` objects, so I tried `FITOPTS (1,1) struct` — which *did* result in a successful object creation. Unfortunately, when later referring to this `FITOPTS` field while trying to call `fit`, I got the following error:

```
Error using fit>iParseOptionalArgs (line 949)
Algorithm options must be specified in a FITOPTIONS object or as property-value pairs.
Error in fit (line 113)
[useroptions, useroptargs, probparams] = iParseOptionalArgs( varargin{:} );
```

Which means that the property validation *cast* the `nlsqoptions` object into a `struct`, losing the "extra information" that it held fit options. While this behavior is an interesting find, it is not very helpful in the present scenario.

**My question**:

Can anybody suggest a way of performing this class validation such that the `FITOPTS` ends up containing a fit options object?

I'm working with R2019b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last error appearing in the question refers to line `949` in `fit`. If we look in this file, we see that the "candidate" fit options object is passed to a function named `isfitoptions` which checks whether it's valid or not.

This hints at a different mechanism of validating inputs - passing them to [validation *functions*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-validator-functions.html). Although these functions are meant to validate the *value*, rather than the *class*, there's no reason they cannot be used for the latter as well. Thus, if MATLAB's function can be invoked by the user, it can be used for validation, and if not, the same test (simple call to [`isa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html)) can be implemented as a method in our own class. Fortunately, this function *is* accessible outside the package/toolbox, and the following leads to the desired result:

```matlab
  properties (Abstract = true, Access = protected, Constant = true)
    MODEL   (1,1) string
    FITOPTS (1,1) {isfitoptions}
  end
```